# How to read from a file until a character is read then skip some characters and continue reading again

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

How do I read from a file till a particular character is reached and then seek to the next character and continue reading in C++.

In my program I am using some HTML syntax and generating a .htm file... So in my C++ code I have added the tags.

But when I read from my .htm file I want it to not include the tags.

What I plan on doing is reading the file till `'<'` is encountered then just seek to the point till `'>'` is encountered and continue reading from there.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but depending on the size of the file (probably small because HTML), you could read the whole file in first. Makes it a bit easier to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that doing this correctly is quite a bit trickier than you apparently think.

Just answering the question as you asked it, you can use `istream::get` to read a character at a time until you get a '<'. You can use `ignore` to ignore characters up to the next '>' in the stream.

Getting back to the first point, however, that generally won't work correctly. In particular, it's entirely possible for a tag to contain a string, and the string (in turn) contain a '>' that is *not* the close of the tag. As such, to have any hope of parsing the HTML correctly, you need to parse for strings inside the tags, and when you find them, skip across their contents rather than treating any '>' they might contain as ending the tag.

Comment: A tag containing an unescaped `>` would be invalid, if it is not a nested tag. I think the best hint is: there are always as many `<` as `>` in a valid html file.

Comment: According to [W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data) normal text can't contain a "<" character, but I see no such restriction on ">".

Answer (score 11):

In general, to read a file until a particular character is reached you use `std::getline` and you set the second parameter to your terminator so if you are reading until a '<' character you can do

```
std::getline( infile, str, '<' );
```

you can then do the same with a `>` character

In your case if you are parsing HTML then there are probably specific parsers for it already. I think HTML1.1 is XML compliant but HTML1.0 isn't as it was not always necessary to close all your tags, so an XML parser will not necessarily work.

You would need to assume that open and close tags are not part of comments or quoted text and the methodology I described above would not promise you that so you'd need a full state machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some guidelines.

- You can read the file line by line with `getLine` from a `ifstream` , and keep each line in a `std::string`
- You can use `std::string.find()` method to find `<` and `>` characters.
- You can use `std::string.substr()` method to get substrings.
- You can group the strings, if required, in a `std::vector`.

You're not going to get a full implementation here, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The following reads from standard input; modify/reaplace the calls to getchar() to read from somewhere else.

```
int c;

c = getchar();
while ( c != EOF ) {
    while ( c != '<' && c != EOF) {
        /* Do something with character outside tag? */
        c = getchar();
    }
    while ( c != '>' && c != EOF ) {
        /* Do something with character inside tag? */
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```